# Assuming nodejs-based webapp runs locally on the encrypted wifi, can it still be hacked outside the wifi?

Tags: node.js, security

If you choose to not deploy your webapp outside your Wifi, simply run nodejs server locally, and access it via `[ip-address/alias]:[port]`, can hackers still access it remotely outside its WiFi?

Comment: Basically it's safe, unless someone can hack into your local network from the internet. e.g. hack into a computer inside your wifi network then they can access your nodejs server in the local network

Answer (score 0):

A hacker would have to gain access to your local network from the outside, which is difficult but possible. Check for open ports on your router. Use WPA2 and disable WPS. If your node app manages critical data, consider password-protecting it, even if you're not going to put it online.